# Is it faster to render a form for each of ~100 records or load individual forms with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, load

I have a Comment model, which has_many Replies. I'm going to have about 100 comments on any given page, and each comment should have the option to write a reply to it. This requires that each comment somehow have its own Reply form.

Which of the following methods would be easier on my server?

**1.)** Load one form per Comment upon page load, and immediately hide each with javascript. Each Comment also has a button which when clicked causes the form to show. The form hides again when the user clicks anywhere else.

**2.)** Each Comment starts out with a button and an empty div. When the user clicks said button, the empty div is filled with the form via ajax. When the user clicks anywhere else, the div is once again emptied.

The form I'm talking about is very simple. It would be something like this:

```
  <%= form_for([@comment, @reply], remote: true ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
    <%= f.submit "Post" %>
  <% end %>
```

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: The fewer network round trips, the better.

Comment: Does that mean that ajax would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Anyway AJAX is better. Your visitors shouldn't wait for all the comments loading to view the page. Load only the main page content, for example the article, and then through AJAX load the comments section.
2. It's very bad design to have 100 hidden empty form. I'd recommend to place or even create the form on demand, i.e. when user clicks the button "say". Pay attention, that the 'classic' asp form with default 'submit' button will reload all the page every time the user posts something. I'd recommend to have just a set of controls and the button 'save' to upload a new comment / answer using AJAX and update the only necessary part of the page on response.
3. Click 'anywhere else' is confusing. 'Save' / 'Cancel' buttons provide much better usability.